# Add Eclipse plugin via dropins on MacOS

Tags: java, eclipse, google-java-format

I used to add a [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format) plugin in Eclipse via drop an e.g. `google-java-format-eclipse-plugin-1.13.0.jar` into a `dropins` folder. On Windows and Linux it always worked.

But on MacOS 12.6 it looks like it doesn't.
Eclipse version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)

Here is how I do it:

1. I have an Eclipse.app in `~/programs/Eclipse.app`
2. Right-click, *Show package content*
3. Pasting a given jar `google-java-format-eclipse-plugin-1.13.0.jar` under: `Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/dropins`
4. (Re)Starting Eclipse

I've also tried with adding `-clean` option in `eclipse.ini` but it doesn't help.

I see that changes in `Eclipse.app` are used, because if I make some change I see an effect (e.g. breaking changes in `eclipse.ini`, then it doesn't start).

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the plugin get moved to the plugins folder? Does it show up in the installed plug-ins list in the Installation Details dialog? Does anything get written to the .log in the current workspace .metadata?

Comment: No error, it's not on the list of installed plugins. However, just for the sake of simplicity, I've downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse and I did the same with a fresh empty workspace...and it works. Strange. Looks like the original Eclipse was broken(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like downloading a fresh Eclipse with a fresh empty workspace solved the problem.